# Javascript in JSF - "body onload=" vs </redirect> tag

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, onload, param

I am trying to use a javascript on one of my JSF pages. Unfortunately the

```
<h:body onload="init('#{formBean.arrayAsString}')">
```

Is not called at all. I have discovered that if I add /redirect tag in the navigation case that navigate to the page, the function will load. Unfortunately that causes another problem since with the navigation I also pass important f:param so the formBean can read it. If I use the /redirect tag the param value is no longer available for reading.

How can I load the javascript init function without using the redirect tag? Or maybe I can somehow pass the f:param value with redirection but as far as I know this is not possible...

I below post the navigation method:

first .xhtml page:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="selectMenu" value="#{indexBean.name_id}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{indexBean.myModelValues}" />    
    <f:ajax event="valueChange" render="button" execute="@this"/>       
</h:selectOneMenu>
                <h:commandButton id="button" value="Go to form Browse" action="form">
                  <f:param name="name" value="#{indexBean.name_id}" />                                       
                </h:commandButton>
```

Bare in mind that this button is also re-rendered by a ajax event of a h:selectOneMenu to pass the selected value.

And the navigation case:

```
 <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/index.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>   
            <from-outcome>
                form
            </from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>
                /form.xhtml
            </to-view-id>
            <redirect/>
        </navigation-case>
        </navigation-rule>
```

The redirect tag is a new add-on which enabled the JavaScript init function.

Comment: you have "<h: body" in your code or is it a typo in the question?

Comment: it is h:body without the space.

Comment: how are you navigating? using a navigation rule in faces-config.xml? or returning a String in the action method? or with commandButton/commandLink action attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will happen if the action is invoked by ajax. Make it a non-ajax action.

---

**Update**: as per your question update, replace `<a4j:commandButton>` by `<h:commandButton>` to make it a non-ajax action. By the way, in JSF 2 you do not need navigation cases anymore if the from outcome equals the to view ID already. Remove the whole `<navigation-rule>`, you don't need it.

Comment: I needed to change some other stuff but it works - Thanks as usual BalusC - great support.